# Como pasar el resultado de un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL a un parámetro de otro procedimiento almacenado MySQL?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, controller

Estoy utilizando CodeIgniter y tengo la siguiente función en mi controlador:

```
public function miFuncion{
  $sql_fecha = "CALL db.spFECHA();";//obtiene una fecha en formato datetime
  $query = $this->db->query($sql_fecha);

  $sql1 = "CALL db.spReport1('".$query."');";            
  $sql2 = "CALL db.spReport2('".$query."');";  
  $query1 = $this->db->query($sql1); 
  $query2 = $this->db->query($sql2);  
}
```

La variable `$sql_fecha` se ejecuta sin problema pues hice una prueba en donde imprimo el resultado en una tabla y no hay ningún problema, pero si deseo utilizar el resultado que esta guardado en `$query` para pasárselo a otro procedimiento no lo considera, he intentado hacer un `echo $query;` pero no imprime nada.

Creo que hay algo que aun no estoy comprendiendo, ya que siempre he realizado las consultas en mi controlador y siempre imprimo el resultado en una tabla pero ahora me encontré con esta nueva situación donde el resultado obtenido tengo que enviárselo en una variable a otro procedimiento almacenado, también cambie la variable `$query` por una fecha fija en los parámetros de `$sql1` y `$sql2` y lo realiza sin problema alguno.

Comment: Puedes imprimir el valor del resultado de tu primera query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando llames a tu SP con parametro es algo asi :

```
//Primer SP sin parametro
$sql_fecha = "CALL db.spFECHA();";//obtiene una fecha en formato datetime
$query = $this->db->query($sql_fecha);
$fecha = $query->row(); 
$fecha = $fecha->fecha;

$sql1 = "CALL db.spReport1('".$fecha."');";            
$sql2 = "CALL db.spReport2('".$fecha."');";  
$query1 = $this->db->query($sql1); 
$query2 = $this->db->query($sql2);
```

Comment: Hola @sioesi oye una pregunta en tu respuesta solo estas considerando el primer SP verdad? osea que `$result` se lo pasaría como parámetro a mis otros 2 SP

Comment: Hola @GuillermoVargas no.. este fue un ejemplo! de como enviar un parametro a tu SP que lo necesita

Comment: si gracias por modificar tu respuesta exactamente asi lo estoy haciendo pero lo raro es que no muestra nada ni marca error, voy a ver si encuentro el error

Comment: pero te aseguraste que el valor de tu primera consulta, esa fecha que dices traer, realmente tiene valor?

Comment: Mira ejecute esto para ver que me trae:                                                            `if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
                    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
                        var_dump($row);
                    }
                }` y el resultado es esto:                                         `object(stdClass)[24]
  public 'fecha' => string '2016-10-21 11:45:19' (length=19)`

Comment: Podrias recuperar el valor de "fecha" e imprimirlo solo, ese debes enviar por parametro

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47184/discussion-between-sioesi-and-guillermo-vargas).